# Access base class(list) properties from derived class c#

Tags: c#, list, nunit

I need to access base class properties which is a list from derieved class. Below is the example.I need this for unit testing.

```
class child : List<Parent>
 {
    //this class is empty.
  }

 class Parent
 {
      public List<Seller> Seller
   {
       get;
       set;
   }

   public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

}

Am not able to access any properties of parent class . Please help.

unit test code

```
[Test]
public class test()
{
  child a = new child();
   a. // not showing any properties of parent
 }
```

Comment: child inherits from  `List<Parent>`, not from `Parent`. So it's a "collection". You'll have to do something like `foreach(var parent in a) {var id = parent.Id;}`

Comment: i dont get parent.id in this case

Comment: what do you mean ? If you don't add any `Parent` in the `List<Parent>` (doing something like `a.Add(new Parent{Id = 2})`), you won't have anything inside, of course...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get `a.ID` ,  `a.Seller` you have to declare:

```
class child :Parent
 {
    //this class is empty.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you derive from a `List<T>` you will inherit its abilities, not the abilities from `T`. What you can do is access one T in the list to access its properties.

```
public class Parent
{
    public bool IAmAParent { get; set; }
}

public class Child : List<Parent>
{ }

var c = new Child();
c[0].IAmAParent = true;
```

From what I'm seeing I have the feeling you are confused about the inheritance you need. If you need to access the `Parent`'s properties in the `Child` then it should inherit from the Parent, then put into a list, not the opposite.

```
public class Parent
{
    public bool IAmAParent { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{ }

var c = new List<Child>();
c[0].IAmAParent = true;
```

Comment: Had already tried this way but c[0]. //doesnt show any property

Comment: Be aware that the list must contain one item at least for the above code to work. Regarding the intellisense no working maybe you have some compilation problem that prevents the base class to be built. Are there other errors in the code?